# How can i run ecto migrations of a dependency?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm building a project, which is going to act as a core for multiple other projects, somewhat like a Rails Engine in ruby world.

I have implemented some base database structure in my core project, basically structure that is shared across the board.

My problem is that my projects, that uses my core, doesn't register the migrations of the core project.

Is there any way i can run migrations of my core dependency?

Let me know if you need more information. :-)

Thank you

Comment: If this is an umbrella application, I just `cd` into the core project and run the migrations. You could also copy the migrations from the core project into each of the projects you need them in. It may be worth creating a mix task to do this.

Comment: Can you give us some more information about your project structure? Specifically, how do you handle your dependencies? do you use a umbrella app, or are they separate packages included as deps?

Comment: No this is not a Umbrella app, i simply just add the dependency in my mix file, which is fetched from git. I don't think i makes sense to make a Umbrella app, as the projects that are going to use the core project, aren't connected in any way. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Ecto.Migrator` module in a custom task.
See [running-migration-in-an-exrm-release](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/04/running-migration-in-an-exrm-release/) for a more detailed explanation.

```
defmodule Release.Tasks do
  def migrate do
    {:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:my_dependency)

    path = Application.app_dir(:my_dependency, "priv/repo/migrations")

    Ecto.Migrator.run(MyApp.Repo, path, :up, all: true)

    :init.stop()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a mix task to help you, by defining a `Mix.Tasks.*` module, like this:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.DependencyApp.Ecto.Migrate do

  use Mix.Task
  alias MyApp.Repo

  def run(args) do
    path = Application.app_dir(:dependency_app, "priv/repo/migrations")
    {:ok, pid, apps} = Mix.Ecto.ensure_started(Repo, [])
    Ecto.Migrator.run(Repo, path, :up, all: true)
    Repo.stop(pid)
  end

end
```

That will let you run `mix dependency_app.ecto.migrate` (taking the migrations from the `dependency_app` app, and using your app's config and repo).